# Parts of speech - But only if

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

How would the phrase "but only if" be labeled grammatically in the sentence: 
I will go to the store, but only if you give me money.

Comment: It's not a phrase, not a single constituent. "But" is a coordinator functioning as a 'marker'. "Only" is a focusing adverb modifying the _if_ preposition phrase, thus there are two constituents, as bracketed: [but] [only if you give me money].

Comment: 'only' modifies the subordinator 'if', which introduces the subordinate clause.  There is no *preposition phrase* there.

Comment: No, Aml: In modern grammar, conditional "if" is analysed as a preposition, and the scopal focus of "only" is the whole PP "if you give me money". This is simply a case of _Q only if P_. "If" is a subordinator when it introduces closed interrogative content clauses (indirect questions), as in "he asked me if [I'd chair the meeting]".

Comment: Even the 'basic' Wiktionary gets it right: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/if)

Answer (score 2):

The ancient and venerable *Warriner' English Grammar and Composition* identifies **if** as a **subordinating conjunction.**

Adding **but only** narrows the condition described in the subordinate clause, but doesn't change the function of the phrase as a whole.